# Check whether a string contain any of the given characters in python?

Tags: python, string

For example 
My string is 'I love you'
characters are 'z' 'p' 'q' 'l'

It should return true because 'I love you' contains 'l'

Comment: This is a fairly basic problem.  What have you tried? Have you googled this?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both the strings to a set and check if there are any common chars by finding intersection

```
>>> set('I love you') & set('zpql')
{'l'}
>>> bool(set('I love you') & set('zpql'))
True
```

Comment: The OP wants a True/False return value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` to do a [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

```
my_string = 'I love you' 
characters = ('z', 'p', 'q', 'l')
print(any(letter in my_string for letter in characters))
```

Will print True if any of the letters in `characters` are contained in `my_string`